# Custom WebDAV Servers and windows explorer

Tags: c#, xml, webdav

I'm trying to get windows explorer to talk to my webdav instance, I have built what i beleive to be a valid PROPFIND response but in a command line when I issue a ...

net use x: https://example.com/Some/Root/Path/

... it goes bang with a ...

> System error 67 has occurred.
>
> The network name cannot be found.

This happens regardless of weather the SSL cert is valid or not and on a proper server deployment and locally using localhost (to debug the process with VS).

I'm using .Net Core 2.2 (in case that matters) and right now none of this "requires" auth, but i do intend to add that once i get a basic request lifecycle working.

The PROPFIND response looks like this ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:">
    <d:response>
        <d:href>https://localhost:44313/Core/App(1)/WebDav/data</d:href>
        <d:propstat>
            <d:prop>
                <d:id>e08c9a0a-4728-41f4-909b-08d71b3f7bc2</d:id>
                <d:name>Data</d:name>
                <d:type>Folder</d:type>
                <d:resourcetype>
                    <d:collection />
                </d:resourcetype>
            </d:prop>
            <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
        </d:propstat>
    </d:response>
    <d:response>
        <d:href>https://localhost:44313/Core/App(1)/WebDav/scripts</d:href>
        <d:propstat>
            <d:prop>
                <d:id>56b353ad-78ba-4ea6-5dc4-08d72181c00c</d:id>
                <d:name>Scripts</d:name>
                <d:type>Folder</d:type>
                <d:resourcetype>
                    <d:collection />
                </d:resourcetype>
            </d:prop>
            <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
        </d:propstat>
    </d:response>
    <d:response>
        <d:href>https://localhost:44313/Core/App(1)/WebDav/icons</d:href>
        <d:propstat>
            <d:prop>
                <d:id>1959b510-b27a-4636-2f54-08d7427b8307</d:id>
                <d:name>Icons</d:name>
                <d:type>Folder</d:type>
                <d:resourcetype>
                    <d:collection />
                </d:resourcetype>
            </d:prop>
            <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
        </d:propstat>
    </d:response>
    <d:response>
        <d:href>https://localhost:44313/Core/App(1)/WebDav/content</d:href>
        <d:propstat>
            <d:prop>
                <d:id>d8c9a4fc-fb5d-461d-d4ee-08d74bdb2d3d</d:id>
                <d:name>Content</d:name>
                <d:type>Folder</d:type>
                <d:resourcetype>
                    <d:collection />
                </d:resourcetype>
            </d:prop>
            <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
        </d:propstat>
    </d:response>
    <d:response>
        <d:href>https://localhost:44313/Core/App(1)/WebDav/documentation</d:href>
        <d:propstat>
            <d:prop>
                <d:id>9e383261-831f-4f75-a62e-08d7725c8272</d:id>
                <d:name>Documentation</d:name>
                <d:type>Folder</d:type>
                <d:resourcetype>
                    <d:collection />
                </d:resourcetype>
            </d:prop>
            <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
        </d:propstat>
    </d:response>
    <d:response>
        <d:href>https://localhost:44313/Core/App(1)/WebDav/test</d:href>
        <d:propstat>
            <d:prop>
                <d:id>771b935d-7ad8-4262-ea25-08d79901323d</d:id>
                <d:name>TEST</d:name>
                <d:type>Folder</d:type>
                <d:resourcetype>
                    <d:collection />
                </d:resourcetype>
            </d:prop>
            <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
        </d:propstat>
    </d:response>
    <d:response>
        <d:href>https://localhost:44313/Core/App(1)/WebDav/testingfiles2001020</d:href>
        <d:propstat>
            <d:prop>
                <d:id>475f4d08-86d4-46f6-692f-08d79d955806</d:id>
                <d:name>TestingFiles2001020</d:name>
                <d:type>Folder</d:type>
                <d:resourcetype>
                    <d:collection />
                </d:resourcetype>
            </d:prop>
            <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
        </d:propstat>
    </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```